# How to get direct access to host network from Virtualbox running Ubuntu?

Tags: 12.04, networking, virtualbox, internet, virtualbox-networking

I'm running Ubuntu on a virtual machine with Virtualbox. The host uses Windows 8. Right now, the guest has internet access, but it's some sort of virtual network because it thinks it's using a wired connection when I'm using wireless.

How do I get my Virtualbox guest to get direct access to the network the host is using?

Comment: I think the only way you could directly connect to the wifi is with an USB network adapter managed by the guest.

Comment: The above link is windows 7, but same configuration should apply.

Comment: Note that, while you may be able to add the machine to the same network of the host (via bridged network), you can not make the VM access the wifi device of the host, unless it is USB. In fact, only one device driver (thus only one operating system) may use the device, so VirtualBox has to unplug it from the host, (which will shutdown its driver,) and plug it into the guest; and while it is possible to plug/unplug USB devices on a running system, VirtualBox can't do it for PCI devices.